# Inserting href into XSLT translated XML files HTML output

Tags: html, xml, xslt

Have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<core:renderedItem renderedContentUUID="e8c957a5-03e0-41f4-83a5-297e43bd660f" family="ResearchOutput" type="ContributionToJournal" rendering="harvard" workflows="researchoutput" workflowStates="approved" external="false" classification="/dk/atira/pure/researchoutput/researchoutputtypes/contributiontojournal/article" state="/dk/atira/pure/publication/status/inpress">
  <div class="rendering rendering_researchoutput  rendering_researchoutput_harvard rendering_contributiontojournal rendering_harvard rendering_contributiontojournal_harvard">
    <span>Reid, CT</span>
    &amp; Nsoh, W 2014, '
    <span class="harvard_title">Whose Ecosystem is it Anyway: Private and Public Rights under New Approaches to Biodiversity Conservation</span>
    '
    <span>
      <em>Journal of Human Rights and the Environment</em>
    </span>
    .
  </div>
</core:renderedItem>
```

I'm new to XSLT and I'm trying to output the XML using XSLT in the following HTML format:

```
<div class="publications">
  <p>
    <span>Reid, CT</span>
        &amp; Nsoh, W 2014, '
        <span class="harvard_title"><a href="http://some.website.com/portal/en/research/whose-ecosystem-is-it-anyway(e8c957a5-03e0-41f4-83a5-297e43bd660f).html">Whose Ecosystem is it Anyway: Private and Public Rights under New Approaches to Biodiversity Conservation</a></span>
    '
    <span><em>Journal of Human Rights and the Environment</em></span>
    .
  </p>
</div>
```

The href link always starts with 'http://some.website.com/portal/en/research/' and the URL needs to be built up from that base + renderedContentUUID.  I've managed this (sort of!) with help from others here but I'm stuck with the need to change the HTML output to build in the href etc.  Also, the "harvard_title" string has to be changed to all lower case and if there is a colon in the title, I need to just take the string up to the colon.  Then all spaces have to be changed into '-'s.  This is how the URL looks at present:

```
http://somewebsite.com/portal/en/research/whose-ecosystem-is-it-anyway(e8c957a5-03e0-41f4-83a5-297e43bd660f).html
```

My xslt so far:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:core="http://atira.dk/schemas/pure4/model/core/stable"
  xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  exclude-result-prefixes="x">

  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:variable name="lower">
    abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="upper">
    ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="pubURL"/>

  <xsl:template match="//*">
    <html>
      <body>
        <h1>Staff Publications</h1>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="//*">
    <h2>Journal Articles</h2>
    <xsl:for-each select="//core:renderedItem">
      <xsl:sort select="@type"/>
      <xsl:choose>

        <xsl:when test ="@type = 'ContributionToJournal'">

      <xsl:variable name="uuid" select ="@renderedContentUUID"/>
      <xsl:variable name="show" select="translate(translate((div/span[@class = 'harvard_title']),' ','-'), $upper, $lower)" />
      <xsl:if test="contains($show, ':')">
        <xsl:variable name="pubURL" select="concat('http://somewebsite.com/portal/en/research/', substring-before($show, ':'),'(',$uuid,').html')"/>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="not(contains($show, ':'))">
        <xsl:variable name="pubURL" select="concat('http://somewebsite.com/portal/en/research/',$show,'(',$uuid,').html')"/>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select ="$pubURL"/>
      <div class="publications">
        <p>
          <xsl:copy-of select="div"/>
        </p>
       </div>
     </xsl:when>
   </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Can anyone shed some light into this for me.  I'm unsure about how to proceed constructing the href from the pubURL and 'inserting' it into the  in the HTML output.

Comment: Link to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23887170/new-to-xslt-how-to-return-text-of-span-class-in-xml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very difficult to answer your question because (1) your XML is not valid and (2) your current stylesheet is confusing (for lack of better word).

To pinpoint the answer to the *exact* problem you asked about: if your stylesheet had the following template (in the appropriate place):

```
<xsl:template match="span[@class='harvard_title']">
    <span class="harvard_title">
        <a>
            <xsl:attribute name="href">
                <xsl:text>http://some.website.com/portal/en/research/</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="translate(translate(substring-before(., ':'), $upper, $lower), ' ', '-') "/>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('(', ../../@renderedContentUUID, ').html')"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
        </a>
    </span>
</xsl:template>
```

then this template would write the following output to the result tree:

```
<span class="harvard_title"><a href="http://some.website.com/portal/en/research/whose-ecosystem-is-it-anyway(e8c957a5-03e0-41f4-83a5-297e43bd660f).html">Whose Ecosystem is it Anyway: Private and Public Rights under New Approaches to Biodiversity Conservation</a></span>
```

Comment: That's insane!  I'm really new to this and really appreciate the help.  One thing though, am I right and thinking that if the "harvard_title" class text doesn't have a colon in it that the string will return empty?  I guess I could use xsl:if to check?

Comment: @KbJ You could either check beforehand (using `xsl:choose`, not `xsl:if`, because you need a result for both states) or just append one to the end of the existing string: `substring-before(concat(., ':'), ':')`.

Comment: That's got it working! Excellent.  All I need to try and figure out now is to get the formatting correct for the output. Needs to be (f.ex) 'Whose Ecosystem is it Anyway: Private and Public Rights under New Approaches to Biodiversity Conservation
Reid, C. T. & Nsoh, W. 2014 In : Journal of Human Rights and the Environment.'  I can't get my head around how I go about walking throught the div that contains all this text and getting it into the right order.. I hope that makes sense?

Comment: @KbJ Perhaps you should post a new question regarding that. But please make sure to include a valid and complete XML input example.